# Present Continuous instead of Present Perfect Continuous?

Tags: present-perfect, present-tense, continuous-aspect

Is it possible to simplify sentences like:

> **"I've been having soy milk for 10 yrs now"**
>
> **"I've been standing here for an hour"***

into:

> **"I'm having soy milk for 10 yrs now"**
>
> **"I'm standing here for an hour"**?

Seems like I've just heard something like that on TV, but I may have missed or misheard the "*vbin*" part.

Comment: *"I am [doing something] **for** [some length of time]"* doesn't sound at all idiomatic to me.

Comment: With those adverbs, the perfect is required.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that without changing the meaning.

The present perfect continuous gives a sense of a continuing thing you've done on and off in the past up until now.

The present continuous makes the sentence mean that you are intending to do this activity for the specified time period.

In other words:

You are going to drink soy milk for 10 years (from this point forward).

You are going to stand here for one hour (from this point until one hour has passed).

You may hear this colloquially, though.

Comment: I'm sure the meaning was past-to-present so I'm guessing I misheard them.

Comment: @jules It is sometimes used (incorrectly) colloquially.

Comment: Is it like fast-speech incorrect? Lazy-incorrect? Uneducated-incorrect?

Comment: @jules uneducated-incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The second form works in other languages like French and German, but is not idiomatic English (certainly not British English and probably not American English either).

In fact it sounds like a slightly imperfect translation from a non-native speaker of English.